# Nucleophilic strength of Fluorine vs iodine

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilicity

Fluorine is less nucleophilic than iodine because it has greater electronegativity. However, in an aprotic solution, it is more nucleophilic than iodine. Why? I read that fluorine is less stable under an aprotic solvent (I don't quite understand why it is less stable; an explanation would be helpful), but anyways, it is STILL more electronegative than iodine, so shouldn't it still be less nucleophilic then iodine?

Another question- What makes something a good leaving group? does it have to do with its nucleophilic strength? Sorry for the three-part question, but I feel like these questions related to each other very well. Thank you